# When I add a third segment to my expressionengine url, the exp:channel:entries stops returning results

Tags: expressionengine, channel, segments

I'm having an issue where a third "segment" in the url will cause **ALL** the exp:channel:entries to stop returning results.

**Example URLs:**
**works fine:** siteurl.com/index.php/one/two
**does not work:** siteurl.com/index.php/one/two/three

**Example Entry Pull:**
    {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category="18" sort="asc"   search:show_toggle="=SHOW" orderby="sort_order"}

Is this some kind of injection that I am unaware of. I have searched through the documentation, and from what I can tell my specification of a category should overwrite anything in the url. I may be botching it up, but there HAS to be something I can do.?
Something I can modify in the channel module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using the [**dynamic** tag parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/parameters.html#par_dynamic) in your Channel Entries tag, ExpressionEngine is *expecting* a URL Segment Variable to contain the **Entry ID** or **URL Title** of your entry.

Since the third URL Segment `/index.php/one/two/three` isn't a numeric Entry ID or URL Title, your Channel Entries query doesn't contain any information.

> By setting `dynamic="no"` you will ensure that the list is not affected by anything passed in the URL.

Since you've written an *extremely specific* Channel Entries Query, be sure to add `dynamic="no"` to your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag loop to have ExpressionEngine *ignore the URL Segments* and instead use the parameters you supply:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" dynamic="no" ...}
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Furthermore, by adding a simple [Conditional Variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/conditional_variables.html#cond_if_no_results) to your code, you will be able to see a message when no results are returned:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" ... }
    {if no_results}Sorry, No Results{/if}

    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Grokking the fundamental [ExpressionEngine's URL](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) concepts and [URL Segments](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html) is important to understanding and troubleshooting issues like this.

Comment: In my EE 2.x MSM setup, in the main site the segment_3 rule is not applicable but the same is being enforced in another site I created using MSM. What is the reason behind this, if it is enforced in new site, then it should be in the default site as well? Advise?

Answer (score 3):

ExpressionEngine looks at the segments which follow /index.php/ as the following:

- the first segment is assumed to be the **template group**
- the next segment is assumed to be the **name of a template** within that template group
- the third segment is assumed to be either the **url_title** of an entry, or, if the segment is numeric, the **entry_id** of an entry

So, in your case, EE is looking to load the **two** template, from the **one** template group, and then display the entry from the **my_channel** channel that's in the category with the ID of **18** and has a url_title of **three**.

Your specification of the category only overwrites any **category** information in the URL. (e.g., **/template_group/template/category/doorstops** or **/template_group/template/C10** would not affect which entries get displayed in your example).

If you want your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag to ignore the URL completely (with the exception of pagination), you can add `dynamic="off"` to your tag parameters.